# Can't get instances of a video (mp4) to play in multiple tabs in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, video, mp4, amazon-s3

I have a mp4 that I would like to play in Chrome.  The mp4 is stored on s3 and has a url like `http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/vid.mp4`

Now when I put that url into Chrome 27.0.1453.94 the video plays.  When I open a second tab and put the url in, the video doesn't play.  Then if I close the first tab, the second tab video immediately beings to play.  I can open an incognito mode browser and get the video to play.

I'm pretty stumped as to what is causing this.  Any ideas or suggestions?  This is part of a larger web app is how I detected the problem.

I'm using Windows 8.

EDIT:  here is a link where the issue is reproducible with
http://www.tools4movies.com/dvd_catalyst_profile_samples/The%20Amazing%20Spiderman%20bionic.mp4

Comment: Do both play if you open different MP4 videos in each tab?  What about when you use other video formats?  Which OS?

Comment: Since this file is stored on a server in that manner, is there any possibility that the file is being opened with R/W permissions which would lock the file for "editing"?

Comment: @techie007 if I open different videos in different tabs, both play.  Windows 8

Comment: @Will.Beninger I don't think s3 allows for that

Comment: What about when you use other video formats?  What about other browsers?

Comment: If you use two different browsers (on the same computer), can you open the same video twice?

Comment: @techie007 same problem with .ogg

Comment: @techie007 also I added a link to an mp4 in question.  Is it reproducible for you?

Comment: Yup, Chrome (same version) on Windows 7 64-bit here does the exact same thing.  This may be worth [submitting as a bug](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?hl=en) to Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, a well know bug, that needs fixing!
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=234779